# FluentNHibernate joined-subclass

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

What is the *current* method of implementing the [joined-subclass](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-joinedsubclass) structure with FluentNHibernate? By "current", I mean by not using deprecated methods such as JoinedSubClass or AddPart.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to map a joined-subclass is to inherit from `SubclassMap` much in the same way you inherit from `ClassMap` for your non-subclass entities.

It's described in the [fluent mapping subclasses](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#wiki-subclasses) section on the [wiki](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki). For automapping please refer to [Automapping Inheritance](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Automapping-inheritance).

Comment: Is this possible using automapping or do you have to revert to non-convention based fluent mapping to get subclass-mapping to work in FNH?

Comment: All those links are dead unfortunately